80's or 70's horror film with 3 stories involving bikers and a female prisoner
It's different horror films in one movie. 
One of them is a group of bikers that go riding down to the woods and sleep there with their motorcycles. They all cut themselves to bring one of the biker friends' dead girlfriend to life. They all put their blood in a cup while she hangs on the cross, while one of the bikers pour blood in her mouth. I think they were drinking beers afterwards. Then they all fall asleep. Suddenly one of the bikers wakes up while everyone is asleep and his dead girlfriend comes back from the dead hanging from the cross. Then she goes up to him and I think stabs him, but I know she ends up killing him. The next morning everyone wakes up and sees him dead then takes off with their bikes. 
Another horror film starts off with this lady always going to see a witch or I think psychic. Then the lady always has to come home to her husband that always puts her down and yells at her. One night she goes and sees the witch/psychic and she gives her something to I think kill him. Then she puts it in his beer. The next day she goes and sees the witch, he drinks the beer and starts turning green. When the wife arrives home she goes to the kitchen and screams because he's green and looks scary then he smacks her so hard that her head went flying in the fridge. At the end the husband opens the fridge to get a beer and her head is just sitting there with blood all over it.
Another horror film is when a girl gets locked up in the cells. I think she gets miserable for being in the cell then ends up cutting herself to death, then passes away in the cell. Then two cops come to check up on her and she's dead, then her spirit comes out of her body walking towards them and kills the two cops.
Those are three films I remember from the movie. But I can't remember the rest. Please help me find the name of this movie or film!! :(

You're looking for the anthology horror film Hellblock 13. Although the year is way off (it's from 1999), this is a cheap Troma production, so it just looks way older.

In a dark and dreary death-row cell block of a women's prison in South Carolina, a deranged female serial killer named Tara reads to her impending executioner three horror stories based on the 'voices' that compelled her to write during her years on death row. In "Watery Grave" a young woman is plagued by constant nightmares of her two missing children whom were reputed to have been drowned. In "White Trash Love Story" an abused, trailer-trash wife decides to get back at her abusive husband by using witchcraft, which doesn't go as planned. In "Big Rhonda" an outlaw motorcycle gang shows it's newest member a blood-oath ritual for one of their long-dead members. But the bikers don't see their newest addition for what he is, but the undead Rhonda does!

Everything you said is there (biker's resurrected lady killing him, abusive husband oozing green stuff and keeping his wife's head in the fridge etc.) The 3rd one you mentioned is actually the frame story, and also unfolds exactly as you've described. Here's the trailer:



